# Timestamp unit in Trips Layer in Deck.gl

Tags: deck.gl

Can anyone help me with the timestamp format in Trips Layer for deck.gl?
Pasting a part of the array,

```
[-74.21055, 40.80768, 1660.904], 
[long, lat, time]
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am using a timestamp from the example right now. But I need to know what is the time format for the time

Comment: See if you can make anything out of this - https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/issues/1854